# pool.map list index out of range python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pool

there is about 70% chance shows error:

```
    res=pool.map(feng,urls)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

don't know why,if data less then 100,only 5%chance show that message.any one have idea how to improve?

```
#coding:utf-8
import multiprocessing
import requests 
import bs4
import re
import string
root_url =  'http://www.haoshiwen.org'

#index_url = root_url+'/type.php?c=1'
def xianqin_url():
    f = 0
    h = 0
    x = 0 
    y = 0 
    b = []
    l=[]


    for i in range(1,64):#页数
        index_url=root_url+'/type.php?c=1'+'&page='+"%s" % i
        response = requests.get(index_url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
        x = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.sons a[href^=/]')]#取出每一页的div是sons的链接
        c=len(x)#一共c个链接
        j=0
        for j in range(c):
            url = root_url+x[j]
            us = str(url)
            print "收集到%s" % us
            l.append(url)  #pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    return l

def feng (url) :
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.encoding='utf-8'
#print response.text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
#content = soup.select('div.shileft')
    qq=str(soup)
    soupout = re.findall(r"原文(.+?)</div>",qq,re.S)#以“原文”开头<div>结尾的字段
    #print soupout[1]
    content=str(soupout[1])
    b="风"
    cc=content.count(b,0,len(content))
    return cc

def start_process():
    print 'Starting',multiprocessing.current_process().name

def feng (url) :
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.encoding='utf-8'
#print response.text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
#content = soup.select('div.shileft')
    qq=str(soup)
    soupout = re.findall(r"原文(.+?)</div>",qq,re.S)#以“原文”开头<div>结尾的字段
    #print soupout[1]
    content=str(soupout[1])
    b="风"
    c="花"
    d="雪"
    e="月"
    f=content.count(b,0,len(content))
    h=content.count(c,0,len(content))
    x=content.count(d,0,len(content))
    y=content.count(e,0,len(content))
    return f,h,x,y


def find(urls):
    r= [0,0,0,0]
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool()
    res=pool.map4(feng,urls)
    for i in range(len(res)):
        r=map(lambda (a,b):a+b, zip(r,res[i]))
    return r


if __name__=="__main__":
    print "开始收集网址"
    qurls=xianqin_url()
    print "收集到%s个链接" % len(qurls)
    print "开始匹配先秦诗文"
    find(qurls)
    print '''
    %s篇先秦文章中：
---------------------------
    风有：%s
    花有：%s
    雪有：%s
    月有：%s
    数据来源：%s
    ''' % (len(qurls),find(qurls)[0],find(qurls)[1],find(qurls)[2],find(qurls)[3],root_url)
```

stackoverflow :Body cannot contain "`pool ma p".
changed it as res=pool.map4(feng,urls)
i'm trying to get some sub string from this website,with multiprocessing.

Comment: We can't really help you unless you A) give us the code, and B) explain what it's trying to do...

Comment: i tried,system said i wrote much too code,i'll try to upload a pic.

Comment: code uploaded..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `multiprocessing` makes it a bit hard to debug as you don't see where the `index out of bound` error occurred (the error message makes it appear as if it happened internally in the `multiprocessing` module).

In some cases this line:

```
content=str(soupout[1])
```

raises an `index out of bound`, because soupout is an empty list. If you change it to

```
if len(soupout) == 0:
    return None
```

and then remove the `None` that were returned by changing

```
res=pool.map(feng,urls)
```

into

```
res = pool.map(feng,urls)
res = [r for r in res if r is not None]
```

then you can avoid the error. That said. You probably want to find out the root cause why `re.findall` returned an empty list. It is certainly a better idea to select the node with `beatifulsoup` than with regex, as generally matching with `bs4` is more stable, especially if the website slightly changes their markup (e.g. whitespaces, etc.)

**Update**:

> why is `soupout` is an empty list? When I didn't use `pool.map` never I have this error message shown

This is probably because you hammer the web server too fast. In a comment you mention that you sometimes get `504` in `response.status_code`. 504 means [Gateway Time-out: The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#504)

This is because haoshiwen.org seems to be powered by [kangle](https://github.com/kangleweb/kangle) which is a reverse proxy. Now the reverse proxy handles back all the requests you send him to the web server behind, and if you now start too many processes at once the poor web server cannot handle the flood. Kangle [has a default timeout of 60s](https://github.com/kangleweb/kangle/blob/master/etc/config-default.xml) so as soon as he doesn't get an answer back from the web server within 60s he shows the error you posted.

How do you fix that?

- you could limit the number of processes: `pool=multiprocessing.Pool(2)`, you'd need to play around with a good number of processes
- at the top of `feng(url)` you could add a `time.sleep(5)` so each process waits 5 seconds between each request. Also here you'd need to play around with the sleep time.

Comment: it worked,but i still don't know why  soupout is an empty list,and when i didn't us `pol map func `,never have this error message shown

Comment: it might be that you're hamming the web server too fast, so it returns either a `50x` response code or a page with `200` and displaying an error. Try `print(response.status_code)` inside the `if len(soupout) == 0` block

Comment: tired,no error msg output,but the  problem seems solved,thank you for your time

Comment: another option is to `print(response.text)` in the if block

Comment: @chenjunjie is this the content of `response.text`?

Comment: @chenjunjie: I've added a section below on what is most probably happening on the server side and what you can do against it

Comment: :thanks a lot,now i get why i cant use multiprocessing,it's too fast……

Comment: you welcome. You can do me a favour back if you'd upvote/accept the answer :-)

Comment: i tried 2 hours ago,but my account 's reputation is too low(only 1) today is my first time login

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.